# Semaphores and shared memory already opened / Problem with O_EXCL flag

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm currently working on a programm that has a shared memory and semaphores. However I have issues with initializing them. Whenever I wanna open them (whilst having the O_EXCL flag active I keep getting erros. That should mean they are already open when starting but I have no idea how or why.

```
static sem_t *s1 = NULL;

void initSEM(void)
{
    atexit(closeSEM);
    s1 = sem_open(SEM_1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 1);
    if (s1 == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        printf("%s", "ERROR: Semaphore 1 could not be opened.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void closeSEM(void)
{
    if (sem_close(s1) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_close(s2) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_close(s3) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_unlink(SEM_1) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_unlink(SEM_2) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_unlink(SEM_2) == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

In my main function I just call this. Same thing for the shared memory. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Are you properly calling `sem_unlink` to delete the named semaphore when all processes/threads have closed it? I see no obvious rules for when/if it will get cleaned if that's not done, and if it's not cleaned up, it will still exist and cause an `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` `sem_open` to fail.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I just edited the post and added my close/unlink function. I thought it would get cleaned by the atexit (closeSEM) function.

Comment: *added my close/unlink function* So if anything fails, you leave the remaining files?

Comment: Looks like when any of the `sem_close` or `sem_unlink`s fail, all the remaining code is skipped by the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, so some/all of the named semaphores aren't unlinked. That's a problem if, say, you open `s1` and `s2`, but something prevents you from opening `s3`, in which case the attempt to close `s3` fails, and you never try to unlink any of them. From there on out, you'll never successfully `sem_open` those names using `O_EXCL`, so `sem_close` will always fail, so `sem_unlink` will never be called. You only need to have run code that fails once, and now it fails forever.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That makes sense, it fixed the bug thank you! However there is a different one but thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as written, need fail to open a single semaphore only once, and from then on, will never properly `sem_unlink` *any* of the semaphores, so they continue existing for the next program run.

The sequence of events is:

1. At some point in development, a `sem_open` fails for whatever reason
2. The corresponding `sem_close` then fails, and you `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` rather than performing any remaining `sem_close` calls and *all* of the `sem_unlink` calls, so the named semaphore continues to exist
3. On future runs, all `sem_open` calls with `O_CREAT`/`O_EXCL` fail (because none of them were unlinked), and the problem is never fixed

The simplest solution is to just remove all the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` calls (perhaps replacing them with debug logging); if the program otherwise ran to completion successfully, cleanup failures aren't that important; it's more important to ensure all the cleanup is performed than to fail-fast when some cleanup fails.

It might also make sense to register separate `atexit` handlers for each named semaphore, and only *after* `sem_open` succeeds for that semaphore, so opening one semaphore doesn't register cleanup functions for all of them, nor does a failed open cause you to schedule cleanup. Doing so would reduce the number of failures expected in common failure cases by limiting cleanup to those cases where it is needed.